# How to send text from Indy TCPServer to TCPClient

Tags: delphi, indy

I need a simple fix in my chat app made with `TIdTCPServer` and `TIdTCPClient`. Please, with no additional code, just to send and receive text.

```
procedure TServerApp1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AContext : TIdContext;
begin
  AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(length(newMSG.Text));
  AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(newMSG.Text);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` has a `Contexts` property containing a list of connected clients. You would have to lock and iterate through that list looking for the client to send to. For example:

```
procedure TServerApp1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Buf: TIdBytes;
  List: TIdContextList;
  Context: TIdContext;
  I: Integer;
begin
  // this step is important, as Length(newMSG.Text) will not
  // be the actual byte count sent by Write(newMSG.Text)
  // if the text contains any non-ASCII characters in it!
  Buf := ToBytes(newMSG.Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);

  List := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
    begin
      Context := TIdContext(List[I]);
      if (Context is the one you are interested in) then
      begin
        Context.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Length(Buf));
        Context.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Buf);
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList
  end;
end;
```

However, I do not recommend sending messages directly to a client like this. That can cause race conditions that may corrupt your communications.  A safer option is to give each client its own thread-safe queue that you can push messages into when needed, and then you can have the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event handler send the queued messages when it is safe to do so.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31042871/65863) to the following question for an example:

[¿How can I send and recieve strings from tidtcpclient and tidtcpserver and to create a chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039580/)

Comment: what the "LockList" and "UnlockList" used for?

Comment: @DJMixRhymez `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. The `Contexts` property is a `TThreadList`, which is a `TList` protected by a `TCriticalSection`. You have to lock the CS to access the list, and then unlock it when finished.

Comment: how to receive data sent by server in tidtcpclient

Comment: @DJMixRhymez to read unsolicited messages from the server, you would need to run a worker thread on the client side and have it continuously reading from the socket.